# Inheritance in sequelize model

Tags: node.js, inheritance, sequelize.js

I have some fields that are very common. `(CreatedBy, CreatedDate, LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdatedDate)`.

When I create a model, is there any way I can inherit these properties in my model?

I looked into the [sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/index.html). But could not find anything relevant there.

Currently I am specifying these properties in each and every model I create:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const conn = require('../common/mssql-connection');

const Member = conn.define('Member', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: "Id",
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: "Name"
  },//Everything below this line is repetitive in other models. Inheritance would be useful here.
  createdDate: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: "CreatedDate"
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: "CreatedBy"
  },
  lastUpdatedDate: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: "LastUpdatedDate"
  },
  lastUpdatedBy: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: "LastUpdatedBy"
  }
})

module.exports = Member;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a "standard" way either, but you can intercept  the original define function of the Sequelize constructor, taking care of your default fields:

```
 const originalDefine =  Sequelize.prototype.define; 

 Sequelize.prototype.define = function(tableName,fields){
    return originalDefine.call(this,tableName, {
          createdBy: { type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,defaultValue:"default 'createdBy' value!!!!" },
           ...fields   
     })
 }
```

Then create your Sequelize instance..

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...)
```

Comment: Made some tweaks to make it work. But the concept was handy. Thanks.